# Selecting rows based on minimum value of one column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to select row with distinct value of column A and with minimal value of Order column in MSSQL DB.

Each record has more columns on the right hand side. I know I should used GROUP BY, but it does throw warnings, when I want to keep the right hand side columns a well.

Data set example:

```
A       | Order |  Multiple columns ...   |
--------+-------+-------------------------+
A1      |  3    |  ...                    |
A1      |  7    |  ...                    |
A2      |  2    |  ...                    |
A3      |  2    |  ...                    |
A3      |  8    |  ...                    |
```

So that I want to get these results:

```
A       | Order |  Multiple columns ...   |
--------+-------+-------------------------+
A1      |  3    |  ...                    |
A2      |  2    |  ...                    |
A3      |  2    |  ...                    |
```

The query I tried to use and throws warning is this one:

```
SELECT A, MIN(Order), Column B, Column C, Column D...
    FROM Table
    GROUP BY A
    ORDER BY A
```

Comment: What is the warning? You are proceeding in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also use *top (1) with ties*

```
select top (1) with ties a, * 
from table t
order by row_number() over (partition by a order by [Order])
```

Comment: This one worked perfectly fine and performing well. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Probably the most efficient method (with the right indexes) is:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.order = (select min(t2.order) from t t2 where t2.a = t.a);
```

The more common approach is to use `row_number()`, which I also recommend.

Answer (score 0):

If your dataset isn't so large that a CTE is out of the question.

```
; WITH
    CTE1 AS
    (
        SELECT
            A
            , Order
            , B
            , C
            , D
            , RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A ORDER BY Order ASC)
        FROM Table
    )

SELECT
    A
    , Order
    , B
    , C
    , D
WHERE (RowNumber = 1)
```